# CronJob objects pod not restarted automatically when new image published

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I've have CronJob object specified to perform a job.

This is the YAML File I've used. I used to publish new image via a CI/CD pipeline.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: name-XXX-XXX
  labels:
    app: name-XXX-XXX
spec:
  schedule: "*/3 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 200
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  suspend: false
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
            cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: xxx-pool
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
          containers:
          - name: name-XXX-XXX-container
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            image: image-name
            envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: name-config
            - configMapRef:
                name: name-config 
            - secretRef:
                name: name-config-secret
            - secretRef:
                name: name-config-secret
            - secretRef:
                name: name-config-secret
            - secretRef:
                name: common-secret
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Whenever, a image is published the pod still runs with old image.

I've tried, if possible to set `restartPolicy: Always` similar to deployment object. But on the pipeline,

*The CronJob "name-XXX" is invalid: spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Required value: valid values: "OnFailure", "Never"*  was thrown and not deployed.

I need to automatically restart the pod to run with new image of cronjob.

Any help would appreciated!.

Comment: Where are you specifying a tag for your container? You need to provide a tag, i.e. `image-name:1.0.0`.

Comment: @DanielMann, The tag is provided, just due to some restrictions I have not included the format. The tag id generated on go depends on the pipeline that runs.

Comment: This is the format `image: XYZ.pkg.dev/XXNAME/XYZ-images/name-XXX-XXX:#{Build.BuildId}#`